# Rescale AnimatedGIF at run-time according to Windows DPI Display Settings?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, scaling

In Delphi XE2, I have a JvGIFAnimator component (from JVCL) on a form. Now, when I run this program on a computer where the Windows DPI Display Settings are set to 125%, while all other GUI elements and system text are scaled up to 125%, the GIF animation unfortunately is not resized. The GIF is embedded in the JvGIFAnimator component with the TJvGIFAnimator.Image property at design time as a TJvGIFImage.

Is there a way to rescale the embedded GIF at run-time according to the Windows DPI Display Settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do this yourself one way or another. There is nothing built in that will automatically rescale. Options include:

1. Decode each frame of the GIF. Use a graphics library to resize the images. Create a new GIF with the resized images.
2. Provide multiple GIFs at different sizes and use the one with size closest to the target.

Of these options, the latter is better. Resizing on the fly will lead to horrid visual artifacts and aliasing. Your animation will look dreadful. Not to mention all the coding involved. Choose option 2.

In fact, this issue is no different for rasterized animations as it is for rasterized static images. Just as you need to provide multiple glyphs for toolbar buttons, you need to supply multiple versions of your rasterized animations.